# Where does Tolkien discuss his bafflement at fans wearing One Ring replicas?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring, j-r-r-tolkien

I'm certain that I read a passage from Tolkien somewhere expressing how disturbed/confused he was that anyone would want to make or possess a [replica of the One Ring](https://www.jenshansen.com/pages/lord-of-the-rings-rings), being as it is a symbol of evil. But I cannot remember where I read this, and my Google-Fu comes up with nothing. Any ideas?

I am not certain that the passage in question was written by Tolkien himself; it could have been a commentator sharing their opinion as to how Tolkien would have reacted to such things. But it was in a published work, not an online comment.

Comment: I know he disliked them but I too can't remember.

Comment: @Edlothiad - He said (to Auden) that he [didn't think that *genuine* lunatics would join a Tolkien society](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9eLCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA359&lpg=PA359&dq=tolkien+%22lunatics%22&source=bl&ots=FQPdxBYb0E&sig=a2HY3d0bIz94K3-vQ2ehmw8pguU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJkYzo3MbYAhXJKMAKHZM3Dw4Q6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=tolkien%20%22lunatics%22&f=false). The implication being that he thought that members would be run-of-the-mill everyday lunatics.

Comment: In [an interview with Time](https://tinyurl.com/yb4vx2k3) it's mentioned that he used to refer to his fans as **"my deplorable cultus"**; *"The funny thing," says Simon Tolkien, grandson of J.R.R. and author of the forthcoming novel Final Witness, "was that he was most famous on your side of the Atlantic. I think the English establishment was slightly suspicious of him." In fact, Tolkien found all the fuss distasteful. "Many young Americans are involved in the stories in a way that I'm not," he once remarked about his fans--or as he called them, "my deplorable cultus."*

Comment: Well, it's his fault for making the _evil_ thing something easy to carry around, and the _good things_, which are _mostly swords_ (Anduril, Glamdring, Sting), well, _swords_. One of these things I can carry about me at all times to expose my appreciation for his work, the other one will get me shot by the police.

Comment: Sounds like he's just being a dumbass snob. That's like George Lucas claiming to be disturbed by kids dressing up as Darth Vader for Halloween. Maybe he should have appreciated he had fans at all instead of insulting them for choosing to wear an artifact of his world to show affinity for his work.

Comment: @n_b you could settle carrying one of galadriel's gifts. Preferably not the rope...

Comment: Concerning the product link you posted, you may be interested to know that Badali Jewelry sells [a significantly cheaper replica](http://badalijewelry.com/The-Lord-of-the-Rings/Lord-of-the-Rings-Rings/gollum-8482-gold-the-one-ring-8482-necklace.html). The main difference between the two is that JensHansen is licensed to make movie replicas and Badali is licensed to make book replicas.

Comment: @n_b Why not the carry around the Elessar, the Necklace of Girion, or the  the Nauglamír?

Comment: Morrigan, @ibid Good points. But I didn't think of them at all- Anduril, after all, is the sword that Boromir, Aragon, the Elves, and the enemies all know about and bring up in conversation, it sticks out in my mind more. I guess another good-guy relic could be the Lothlorien clasps that they all wear?

Comment: @n_b To be fair, I can tell you I paid more for that leaf shaped brooch than what a decent ring replica would have costed....

Answer (score 18):

### While not specifically about *wearing* one ring replicas, Tolkien expressed his distaste for fans using its inscription in Letter #343.

> **343. From a letter to Sterling Lanier 21 November 1972**
>
> I am glad to know that you were awarded a prize, but not surprised that it proved useless. I had a similar disappointment when a drinking goblet arrived (from a fan) which proved to be of steel engraved with the terrible words seen on the Ring. I of course have never drunk from it, but use it for tobacco ash.
>
> <sub>*Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien*</sub>

Comment: This is a pretty moot answer, which doesn’t answer the question given that there is a quote from Tolkien on the matter

Comment: @Edlothiad - It's a quote from Tolkien expressing bafflement at fans using the one ring inscription, being as it is a symbol of evil.